# Callback called on associated parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I have a model Project that has many Reports (I'm shorthanding code here)...

```
Project
  has_many :project_reports
  has_many :reports, :through => :project_reports

ProjectReport
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :report

Report
  has_one :project_report
  has_one :project, :through => :project_report
```

I have a validation in Report that checks to make sure there isn't a report with the same date on it so I don't get duplicates with the same date in the scope of the project.

```
Validation
  unless self.project.reports.where(:report_date => self.report_date).empty?
    self.errors.add(:report_date, "report already exists for this date")
  end
```

When this validation is called in Report the callback after_update is called on Project instead of the callback in Report. Specifically this happens when I reference the project association. So even if I just do this...

```
Validation
  self.project
```

It calls after_save in Project instead of in Report. Any help or clarification would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I get you correctly or not. But probably you want to use [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated)

Comment: No, but thanks. I don't want the Project callback called nor do I think it should be called if I'm updating a Report record.